# How do I intuitively understand that the variance of the population mean will always be greater than the variance of the sample mean?

Tags: statistics, means, standard-deviation, sampling

I am currently trying to figure out why “n-1” is used in statistics, but the first component of figuring this out is that supposedly the sample mean “minimizes” the variance of the observations, making it so that it can never be greater than the variance of the observations from the population mean. Apparently this is because the positive and negative distances between the observations and sample mean add up to zero. The population mean, unless it is the same value as the sample mean, will either be to the left or the right of the sample mean, thus causing an imbalance with positive or negative sum. However, I’ve also been told the reason population mean can’t be below the sample mean is because the differences have to be squared anyway, preventing there from being any negative differences. But if this is true, how can the differences from the sample mean cancel out to zero? The only reason they cancel out is because once you add them together, you are including both negative and positive values.

For example, let’s say I have the observations 2 and 6. The mean of this sample is 4. If I add up the deviations from the sample mean (-2 and +2), they will cancel out to zero. But if the population mean is, say, 5, that would make the sum of the deviations from the population mean -2 (-3 and +1). -2 is less than 0, but this can’t be because the variance of the population mean can only be greater than the variance of the sample mean? But then if we square them to ensure there are no negatives, that would also prevent the variance of the sample mean from canceling out to zero (it would go from -2 and 2, to +2 and +2, which would equal 4. Or if squared and added (4+4), would be 8)

I understand if the population mean goes above the highest observation of the sample, as that would increase the distance from all the observations and make a larger sum. But what if the population mean is actually above the sample mean, but lower than the highest observation of the sample. The distance on one side has been increased, but lowered on the other side, so wouldn’t this also cancel or average out to be the same? Using the same numbers from above (2 and 6 with a sample mean of 4 and population mean of 5) for the sample mean, the (positive) deviations (2 and 2) would equal 4, and for the population mean (5), which would shift it one unit to the right and change the deviations to 3 and 1 (|2-5| and |6-5|) would also add to 4?

I would appreciate it if someone could explain in layman’s terms and not use all the greek symbols and hieroglyphics, because that’s what got me into this mess. Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to keep in mind that *population mean* and *population variance* are **parameters** and not statistics. These quantities are not random and are viewed as constants. On the other hand, sample means and sample variances are random variables.

Comment: The mean of the sample is the central value which minimises the sum of the squares of the differences between the individual sample values and a central value.  You can prove this with greek symbols and hieroglyphics.  Let's demonstrate (not prove) this with your numbers: $(2-4)^2+(6-4)^2=8$ while $(2-4.001)^2+(6-4.001)^2=8.000002$ which is bigger than $8$.  Something similar would happen with any other central value not equal to $4$, including the population mean.

Comment: Mind explaining how exactly that works? I’m not saying I disbelieve your math. I just wanna know the “why” behind it. It just seems counter-intuitive to me that the sample mean necessarily minimizes the squares of the differences.

Comment: One way to show it is to show $\frac{d}{dm}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-m)^2 = 2nm-2\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} x_i$ which is $0$ only when $m=\frac1n \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} x_i=\bar x$, i.e. the sample mean.  But that uses greek symbols.  An alternative is to show $(x_1-m)+\cdots+(x_n-m)^2 = (x_1-\bar x)+\cdots+(x_n-\bar x)^2 + n(\bar x-m)^2$ but that takes more effort

Comment: But that’s just the formula. I’m more or less asking how it’s derived (why that formula gets you the answer). If I were the one who discovered this formula, what would be the “aha” that would make it intuitively obvious to me. Because right now, I’m not seeing what they’re seeing

Comment: An 'intuitive' argument for the $n=1$ in the denominator of $S^2 \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X))^2$ is that once $\bar X$ is known, if you knew only $n-1$ of the $X_i,$ then you could figure out the value of the missing one, because $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = n\bar X.$ One says that there remain only $n-1$ "degrees of freedom." Thus $E(S^2) = \mu,$ Whereas dividing by $n$ would make $S^2$ too small as an estimate of $\sigma.$

Comment: More formally, degrees of freedom become the number of dimensions. If you have $n$ observations you can plot them into an $n$-dimensional plot. With a transformation you can put $\bar X$ along one dimension and $n-1$ terms that sum to the numerator of $S^2$ into the remaining $n-1$ dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a random sample $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ from a population with $X_i \sim\mathsf{Norm}(\mu,\sigma).$ It is not necessarily true that the sample variance $S^2 > \sigma^2.$

Example, in R: The sample below has $S^2 = 123.35 < \sigma^2 = 15^2 = 225.$

```
set.seed(710)
x = rnorm(10, 100, 15); sd(x); var(x)
[1] 11.10642   # sample SD
[1] 123.3525   # sample variance
```

In general,  $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu=n-1)$
For the example above $E(S^2) = \sigma^2.$ Here is a simulation of $100\,000$ such sample variances. The mean of the distribution of $S^2 = V$ is $225$ with a large variance. So a considerable proportion of these sample means takes values above 225: $P(S^2 > 225)\approx 0.44.$ (The distribution of $S^2$ is a multiple of a chi-squared distribution.)

```
set.seed(2021)
v = replicate(10^5, var(rnorm(10,100,15)))
mean(v); var(v)
[1] 225.4242
[1] 11359.52
mean(v > 225)
[1] 0.43901

hist(v, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
 abline(v=225, lwd=2, col="red")
```

[image]